# Fastest way to filter records from a heavy collection of datarows (500k-1m records)

Tags: c#

I am working on heavy data (500k-1m records). I need to filter these records in milliseconds.

Currently I am using list with `FindAll` method in C# but it takes at least 1 second to filter records from 200k records.

I have used something like below:

```
var FilteredRecords = ListofAllRecords.FindAll(row => row["ID"].tostring().StartsWith("value"))
```

Is there any other faster way to do this (in the order of milliseconds)?

Comment: Can you share the actual code? Make some profiling to know where the limit is now (row indexer, ToString method or StartsWith method). Try to eliminate it and use parallel processing.

Answer (score 2):

I got a hint from your replies and solved my question by using below code-

```
var FilteredRecords = ListofAllRecords.AsParallel().Where(row => 
                          row.Field<string>("ID").tostring().StartsWith("value"))
```

Now it is taking milliseconds only.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy FindAll is the fastest, because it doesn't use the iterator pattern like Where (Linq).
What you can try is doing the filtering parallel

```
        var filteredRows = new List<DataRow>(ListofAllRecords.Count / 5);
        Parallel.For(0, ListofAllRecords.Count, i =>
        {
            if (ListofAllRecords[i].Field<string>("ID").StartsWith("value"))
            {
                filteredRows.Add(ListofAllRecords[i]);
            }
        });
```